# Terminal - Application behaves differently when launched as terminal argument vs terminal command

Tags: shell, terminal, environment-variables

I use key shortcuts to launch commonly used applications in i3. Some of these applications are text-based (vim, calcurse) and require me to pass them as arguments to a terminal emulator (st, termite). The problem I'm seeing is that my configs are not being used when launching them this way.

Opening a terminal window first then typing in the application name starts it using the config files in my ~/.config directory.

Launching an application as an argument seems to ignore my configuration files and lockfiles. For example, calcurse typically allows only one active session and will warn you that it is already running if you try to run a second instance. However, when launching one instance of calcurse from the commandline and the other with something like "st calcurse" both instances will run concurrently (with different calendar data and theming).

The solution I'm looking for would have `st <application>` behave the same as just running `<application>` from the commandline of a running terminal. It seems like there might be some environment variables that aren't being respected somewhere but I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get different results in the three created files from `st sh -c "env >/tmp/env.st"` and `sh -c "env >/tmp/env.sh` and `env >/tmp/env`? If so, it's a difference in the environment passed to your target application. If not, there's something else going on.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I see one difference: env has SHLVL=2 and env.st, env.sh both have SHLVL=3.

Comment: I tried this again from within nvim. Running `!env >/tmp/env.nvim` gives me a slightly different result depending on if I launched neovim as a command vs argument. Launched using an argument with `st` then `SHLVL=1`. `BASE16_THEME` is also missing for some reason but I don't see any paths missing that might lead to an application using different config files...